# is it possible save data from different view controller and show it at same tableviewcell?

Tags: swift, core-data

my project have A table view controller & B view controller.

A have name, company & phone number need fill in.
B just have job number need fill in.

I expect when I finished A then click next button then go to B page.
and B page had save button, it can save A & B user info (core data)

I expected "777777"(Job number) will show it at same table view cell
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt6HH.png)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do:

Save info like name, etc on ViewController A in a dictionary.

Pass it to viewController B while pushing it over stack.

In B ViewController modify existing dictionary that you passed from A VC and append new key - job number in it.
Then simply save it using core data.

[Check it out for core data](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't understood how to make the B's data let it show at same tableview cell.
Could you kindly provide some sample code for me?
Thank you very much again!!

Comment: you mean what you save in B should be shown up in A tableview

Comment: um..actually, I have three viewcontroller.
A & B need input user info in it.
viewcontroller C will show A & B info.

Comment: Now, the problem is when I input info (A&B),
it can't show the info at the same tableviewcell..
Thank you for your help!!!